# Strange behaviour of Highcharts boxplot

Tags: highcharts, rendering, boxplot

I was testing the new Boxplot graph created by the Highcharts team, located at :
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot

So it is rendered very well.

So I decided to add more values (more observed values) in the last array of the observations data :

```
series: [{
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [
                [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
                [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
                [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
                [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
                [834, 836, 864, 882, 910, 888, 888, 888]
            ],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
            }
        }, {
```

Then the updated boxplot was very ugly.
So I was wondering if this is a normal behaviour ?

Indeed number of observed values can be differents from an experiment to another and it seems that this case can not be displayed by the boxplot highcharts ?

Or is there any option to handle this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Fred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum amount of boxplot parameter is 5.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Thanks for your response it make me realized that I didn't understand the meaning of the 5 data points (parameters) for the boxplot. I should have take time to look into the documentation before playing with it.